# Locking out a user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

As an admin, I would like to be able to click a user and make it so that they can't log in, and I tried this, but it didn't seem to work.

Any tips?

```
public void LockUser(int Id)
    {
        var UserMan = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = UserMan.FindById(Id);
        user.LockoutEnabled = true;
        UserMan.Update(user);
    }
```

Comment: Please note that the tag [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions about the *pattern*. You've already tagged it with the relevant ASP.NET implementation, so you don't need to (and shouldn't) add the pattern tag.

Comment: pretty sure you would actually need an instance of the `ApplicationDbContext` and call the `dbContext.SaveChanges()` method after updating the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but need one thing: The LockoutEnabled should indeed be set to true, but all this does is allow this user to *be* locked out. You need to actually lock him out. You do this by specifying a lockout end date, so the complete code will look like this:

```
    public void LockUser(int Id)
    {
        var UserMan = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = UserMan.FindById(Id);
        user.LockoutEnabled = true;
        user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
        UserMan.Update(user);
     }
```

The above code will lock a user out for 2 weeks. See [this blog post](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-user-lockout/) for more info.